# Make thumbnail big and small with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, thumbnails, image-resizing

[image]

I've trying for a couple hours to make the thumbnail (image in my html) big when clicking it and small when clicking it again but it only gets bigger, and not smaller when clicking it for another time; the small class is in my css code, Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    let thumbnail = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

    thumbnail.onclick = () => {
        thumbnail.className = ""
    }
        
    if (thumbnail.className == "") {
        
        thumbnail.onclick = () => {
            thumbnail.className = "small"
        }

    } else {

        thumbnail.className = "small"

    }

})
```

Comment: do not reinvent class list toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const thumbnail = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

    thumbnail.onclick = () => {
        thumbnail.classList.toggle('small');
    }
});
```

Comment: got this :Uncaught TypeError: thumbnail.className.toggle is not a function
    at thumbnail.onclick

Comment: My mistake. I meant to write `classList` (not `className`). Updated my answer.